# .NET UserControl inherit parent form background

Tags: .net, user-controls, treeview, background

I have a WinForms control inherited from TreeView and I want it to automatically adjust background color according to the form (also customized) background. How to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a control aware of its parent is normally a bad idea.  There however is a dedicated method to detect the parent BackColor changing so it's okay.  BackColor is an *ambient* property, if it isn't explicitly assigned then has the same value as the parent's BackColor.  So take advantage of that:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyTreeView : TreeView {
    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e) {
        if (this.Parent != null) this.BackColor = this.Parent.BackColor;
        base.OnParentChanged(e);
    }
    protected override void OnParentBackColorChanged(EventArgs e) {
        this.BackColor = this.Parent.BackColor;
        base.OnParentBackColorChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***If you were using some other control apart from the `TreeView`, the following advice would apply:***

I haven't tried this on the `TreeView` control specifically, but the WinForms convention is that [setting `control.BackColor = Color.Transparent` causes the parent background to show through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.transparent.aspx).

Comment: Doesn't work for TreeView (no support for Transparent backcolor)